# New Role assignment in SSRS 2005 for about 150 users

Tags: reporting-services, reportingservices-2005

I have our internal clients (about 150 users) wanting to access a SSRS report in Report Server 2005. They all don't belong to the same AD group, and creating a new AD group for this purpose is out of scope.

I believe the only option I have is to manually create 150 user role assignments. Since it's tedious to do that and a nightmare to manage, I wanted to see if anyone out there solved a situation such as this without having to input these manually?  I looked to see if there was something similar like data-driven subscription, so I can place all these Domain\UserID values in a table to read from, to do role assignments, but it doesn't seem to be possible. Can someone please confirm if the manual option (add a user at a time) is the only option I have?

Comment: Can't you add all these users to a local group on SSRS box and give that group a role?

Comment: I'm not an Admin on the SSRS box, plus this means that each time there's a change to this user list, I have to approach the SSRS admin guy. I was looking to see if this can be data driven.

Comment: But you were willing to do that for 150 manual role assignment?

Comment: Only because that way I don't have to depend on someone outside my group. Let's just say the Admins are not easy to work with : (

Comment: Sorry, I may have misunderstood your comment. The manual role assignments I have access to create. But I'm not sure about creating a group and assigning users to that group? 

What kind of access is needed to create a group? I just checked Report Server and I don't see the option available to create a group.

Comment: By "manual" you mean programmaticaly e.g. WebService call?

Comment: By manually adding, I mean going to Report Manager for that report, click on Security, "New Role Assignment", type in each Domain\UserId, selecting the role (which is the same for all users) and clicking OK. This way I have to do this 150 times for the 150 users.

Comment: I think it may be worth grinding teeth and asking admin to create group to add all those users. And for you just add one group and assign it the role. This way it will be waaaaay more managable. Hey you're all in the same boat, no?